# Is there a cleaner way to return result of array from Rails ActiveRecord Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have this method. I'm looping through each client and then checking to see if that client is eligible for terms or not. I feel that this is really inefficient. I believe that a method should return the value of the last action performed, but I still have to do this:

```
  def self.terms_qualifying
    qualifying_client = []
    Client.all.each do |client|
      qualifying_client << client if client.is_terms_eligible?
    end
    qualifying_client
  end
```

I know I can clean this up a little by doing this:

```
  def self.terms_qualifying
    qualifying_client = []
    return Client.all.each do |client|
      qualifying_client << client if client.is_terms_eligible?
    end
  end
```

But I feel like either I'm misunderstanding a key concept or I am just really not getting it. Can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Can you provide the code written for `is_terms_eligible?` in client mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of building an array yourself, you can simply loop over all your clients and choose the ones you're interested in with [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-select)

```
def self.terms_qualifying
  Client.select(&:is_terms_eligible?)
end
```

Though if your `is_terms_eligible?` method can be moved to an SQL query, it could make everything even faster.

If you would still like to write your loop in a cleaner way, this would be the equivalent of above select:

```
Client.all.each_with_object([]) do |client, array|
  array << client if client.is_terms_eligible?
end
```

as [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) returns the object you've created inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

Is is_terms_eligible a property persisted in the database as a boolean?
In that case it would be possible to do something like this:

```
Client.where(is_terms_eligible: true)
```

That would be much more performant.